# Can't connect using aws-iot-device-sdk-v2 for JavaScript using working certificates

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I was able to connect without issue using the legacy version of the JavaScript SDK, but v2 yields the following error when running [the pub_sub sample](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/tree/main/samples/node/pub_sub):

```
events.js:353
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

CrtError: Failed to connect: libaws-c-mqtt: AWS_ERROR_MQTT_UNEXPECTED_HANGUP, The connection was closed unexpectedly.
    at /Users/calebbrewer/dev/node-sandbox/node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk-v2/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/native/mqtt.js:333:36
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
Emitted 'error' event on MqttClientConnection instance at:
    at MqttClientConnection.emit (/Users/calebbrewer/dev/node-sandbox/node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk-v2/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/common/event.js:75:22)
    at /Users/calebbrewer/dev/node-sandbox/node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk-v2/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/native/mqtt.js:333:22
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  error: 'Failed to connect: libaws-c-mqtt: AWS_ERROR_MQTT_UNEXPECTED_HANGUP, The connection was closed unexpectedly.',
  error_code: undefined,
  error_name: undefined
}
```

I provisioned my certificates manually through the console, using the "Create things" workflow.

Any ideas on how to further debug this issue would be appreciate - I've hit a wall!

**Edit**
I discovered the following error in my CloudWatch logs, with some values truncated:

```json
{
  "timestamp": "2021-09-02 16:27:13.163",
  "logLevel": "INFO",
  "traceId": "93d42145-31af-ed6c-7f16-80031602970c",
  "accountId": "$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID",
  "status": "Success",
  "eventType": "Subscribe",
  "protocol": "MQTT",
  "topicName": "topic_1",
  "clientId": "caleb-test",
  "principalId": "f....2",
  "sourceIp": "7...2",
  "sourcePort": 40494
}
```

Copying my policy for this thing since the fact this is hitting the Cloud is making me wondering if that could be causing issues:

```json
{

  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Publish",
        "iot:Receive",
        "iot:RetainPublish"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topic/sdk/test/java",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topic/sdk/test/Python",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topic/topic_1",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topic/topic_2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Subscribe"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topicfilter/sdk/test/java",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topicfilter/sdk/test/Python",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topicfilter/topic_1",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topicfilter/topic_2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Connect"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:client/sdk-java",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:client/basicPubSub",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:client/sdk-nodejs-*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the resources defined in the `iot:Connect` statement of the policy were to blame: the only resource needed is the actual client itself. The following policy has resolved the issue for me:

```json
{

  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Publish",
        "iot:Receive",
        "iot:RetainPublish"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topic/sdk/test/java",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topic/sdk/test/Python",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topic/topic_1",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topic/topic_2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Subscribe"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topicfilter/sdk/test/java",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topicfilter/sdk/test/Python",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topicfilter/topic_1",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:topicfilter/topic_2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Connect"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:client/caleb-test"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```